# In which format are TuneIn streams?

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I attempt to intercept a Web radio stream, e.g. [Flower Power Radio via TuneIn](http://flower.serverhostingcenter.com:8433/;), reason being time–frequency analysis for music signals.

However, to do the analysis, I first need to identify what I obtain from said provider. How can I determine what is what, is there a standard header, where is it described?

The first few bytes from the stream read (num: dec hex):

```
 1: 255 FF
 2: 251 FB
 3: 146 92
 4:  68 44
 5: 209 D1
 6: 128 80
 7:   3  3
 8:  90 5A
 9:  94 5E
10: 223 DF
11: 105 69
12:  42 2A
13:  46 2E
14: 158 9E
15:  98 62
16:  73 49
17:  75 4B
18: 173 AD
19:  24 18
20: 169 A9
21: 217 D9
22: 142 8E
23:  29 1D
24: 121 79
25: 113 71
26: 180 B4
27: 149 95
28:   0  0
29:  49 31
30: 153 99
31:  44 2C
32: 175 AF
```

---

**Edit:** From [this](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html) I think I am able to interpret the file as MPEG, from within the first 4 bytes translating to:

```
MPEGv1, Layer I, NotProtected, 288 kbps, 44100 Hz, 
padded, , Stereo, band 4 to 31, no (c), Original, no Emphasis
```

But still no idea, where the frequences begin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget http://flower.serverhostingcenter.com:8433/` says the file type is `audio/mpeg`. `file` on the resulting download confirms that it's

```
MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
```

or in other words, MP3. `mediainfo` tells you even more, e.g. that it was encoded with LAME3.98.4. You don't really need to intercept it, it plays fine directly, e.g. with

```
mplayer http://flower.serverhostingcenter.com:8433/
```

Comment: thanks. I need the frequency data to do statistics, in this case,I don't care for the actual music (but evenso, I like to drop in all now and then ;)